# Assert the variable value in array list using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to find variable value in Array list but error popup displayed.

Groovy code :-

```
def testCase = messageExchange.modelItem.testCase;
def Created_BookingID = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Created_BookingID");
log.info Created_BookingID


import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
String jsonString = context.expand('${ListAllRoomBookings#Response}')
Map convertedJSONMap  = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString)
def RoomID
//If you have the nodes then fetch the first one only
if(convertedJSONMap."RoomBookings"){

     RoomID = convertedJSONMap."RoomBookings"."BookingData"."BookingID"
     log.info RoomID
}

//Find the created booking in list.
assert Created_BookingID.containsAll(RoomID)
```

Error :-
No signature of method: java.lang.String.containsAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[148281, 148282, 148277]] Possible solutions: contains(java.lang.CharSequence), contains(java.lang.CharSequence), contains(java.lang.String), notifyAll()

Print Values in window :-

```
Wed Aug 02 17:17:22 IST 2017:INFO:148277
Wed Aug 02 17:17:22 IST 2017:INFO:[148281, 148282, 148277]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert Created_BookingID.containsAll(RoomID)
```

> No signature of method: `java.lang.String.containsAll()`
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) 
>   values: [[148281, 148282, 148277]]

you try to call `containsAll()` method on String object. this means that `Created_BookingID` vaiable at this point is String.

if you want to check that string `Created_BookingID` is in array `RoomID`
code will be like this:

```
assert Created_BookingID in RoomID
```

Comment: Now the error display :- assert Created_BookingID in RoomID | | | 148277 | [148281, 148282, 148277] false

Comment: are you sure the `RoomID` also contains String values (the same type as `Created_BookingID`) ? to check the datatype of `RoomID` element - call this: `log.info( RoomID[0].getClass().toString() )` .  cast the data type of  `Created_BookingID` before assertion to `RoomID` type.

Comment: Thanks. 'Created_BookingID' is in String where as 'RoomID' is in Integer.